# Using superclass method to calculate price

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract, superclass

I am doing a problem on inheritance and hierarchy of classes.
The problem is this: I have superclass that contains quantity as the attribute.
The code for that class is here:

```
class Items {
 private int quantity;

 public Items(int quantity) {
   this.quantity = quantity;
 }
```

Then i  have two subclasses that contains prices and other attributes.
Code snippet:

```
class Coffee extends Items {
 private String size;

 public Coffee (int quantity, String size) {
  super(quantity);
  this.size = size;
  }
}

class Donuts extends Items {
 private double price;
 private String flavour;

 public Donuts(int quantity, double price, String flavour) {
   super(quantity);
   this.price = price;
   this.flavour = flavour;
  }
}
```

**What i want to do is calculate the total price for each object.**

My program reads a text file and creates object and stores them in an arrayList. The text file i am reading is this, **Please note i have commented the first two lines just to explain what each token is, They are not included in the real file.**:

> Coffee,3,medium // *name of item then the quantity and then size*
>
> Donut,7,0.89,chocolate // *name then quantity then price then flavor*
>
> Donut,3,1.19,eclair
>
> Coffee,1,large

I want to calculate the total price without duplication of the code. What i have done so far in my superclass is this:

```
 public double totalPrice(Items x) {
   double total = 0;
   if(x instanceof Coffee) {
     total = getQuantity() * getSizePrice();
   } else {
     if (x instanceof Donuts) {
       total = totalPrice();
      }
    }
   return total;
 }
     

 public abstract String getSizePrice();
```

In my `Coffee` subclass:

```
public double getSizePrice() {
  double priceSmall = 1.39;
  double priceMed = 1.69;
  double priceLar = 1.99;

  if(size == "small") { 
    return priceSmall;
  } else {
   if (size == "medium" ) {
     return priceMed;
    }
  }
  return priceLar;
}
```

I believe i am going in circles with this one so i was wondering if the SO community could guide me in the right direction. If the question is confusing, feel free to ask and i would explain it further.
Is it possible to get a `totalPrice()` method in each class and then through ploymorphism the class calculates the price of those items in the main method.

Comment: Instead of checking for instance of subclasses and implementing specifically *in the superclass*, put a method in subclasses to get price by doing whatever with quantity and unit price. In the superclass, just sum them all together

Comment: Won't i need a dummy class in the superclass for those methods to work? I tried that way but the compiler was giving me error @AndrewLi

Comment: Make `totalPrice` an abstract method, and then override it in each subclass as needed.

Comment: getQuantity and getPriceSize are methods of the subclasses so you can't just call them like that. I suspect it should be x.getQuantity for example.

Comment: @Saad Have an abstract method in the superclass which get's the total price of all items of that type. Then in the superclass call those methods and sum.